# MySQL DB Structure Advice

Tags: mysql, structure

I'm looking to create an order history for each client at work using MySQL.

I was wondering if it is best practice to create a separate table for each client, with each row identifying an order they've placed - or - to have one table with all orders, and have a column with an identifier for each client, which would be called to populate their order history.

We're looking at around 50-100 clients, with 10-20 orders a year that would be added to each of them so I am trying to make this as efficient as I am, performance wise.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is never a good idea to create a separate table for specific data (e.g. per client) as this destroys relational integrity / flexibility within the RDBMS itself.  You would have to have something external that adds/removes the tables, and the tables wouldn't have integrity between each other.

The answer is in your second sentence: One table for orders that has a column that points to the unique identifier for clients.  This is as efficient as possible, especially for such small numbers.

Comment: Great, I'll go for the second approach. Thanks for the insight.